# How to perform an histogram with the following dictionary?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a dictionary called dict that looks as follows:

```
var dict = {
  'Ex': 6,
  'C': 6,
  'blue': 2,
  'car': 2,
  'yellow': 2,
  'X': 4,
  'X3': 2
};
```

I would like to plot an histogram of it, with the keys as the labels of the horizontal axis and the values of the dictionary that are the frecuency as the vertical axis, I tried:

```
<canvas id="myChart" width="100" height="100"></canvas>
var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: {
        labels: [],
        datasets: [{
            label: '# Frecuencies Words',
            data: [],

            borderWidth: 1
        }]
    },
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

However the problem is that I am not sure of how to proceed to use the values of the dictionary to perform the graph, I would like to appreciate any suggestion to achieve this, I built the following jsfiddle to explain better the situation: https://jsfiddle.net/xbbc677o/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not doing bad, all you need now is to map that object into the `data` and `label` fields. Let's begin with `labels`

`Object.keys(dict)` returns an array of all the keys from `dict`

So we put

```
labels: Object.keys(dict)
```

Now we need the values for the `data` array, with `Object.keys` and `map` we can do it easily, we use `Object.keys` to get an array of all the keys in `dict` and then `map` to get each value from it's key, like this:

```
data: Object.keys(dict).map(function (key) { return dict[key]; })
```

[Working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xbbc677o/1/)

Both `Object.keys` and `map` are part of the ECMAScript 5 specification, so this wont work on ES3 (IE 8 or lower), but you can get pollyfils for both of those functions:

- [Array.prototype.map polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map#Polyfill)
- [Object.keys polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys#Polyfill)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the support, I really appreciate the help.